# Update Cursor not updating field correctly

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I've got an issue with an update cursor not working correctly. The kicker is that when I dissolve by the field that isn't updating correctly, the output is actually correct. I have the same syntax on a different feature class, and it's working correctly. I've double checked field types - everything is good. I can't figure out why this is happening...

relevant code:

```
#populate DSA fields above threshold with current/correct assignment
arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Populating DSA_Revised field with DSAs above the LOC: " +    str(Threshold))
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(OriginalSA,[DSA_Field,DSARevised_Field,LOC_Field],whereClause_UpdateCursor) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0] #Populate DSA_Revised field with DSAs that are above the user specified threshold
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        Assigned_List.append(row[0])#append entry to a list that will be used in later loop
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not correctly*? Does it spit out an error or is it just not doing what you wanted it to?

Comment: Maybe switch around the updating and the appending to the array. Perhaps *row* is discarded after the *updateRow* and therefore nothing can be added to your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, the variable pointing to the feature class was re-defined - so the update cursor was acting on a different feature class.